# As would be appropriate to make an exception in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method `parse_date_if_not_null` which parses the date and time. But it so happens that the user entered an incorrect date format and time, then you need to show the error. I implemented it this way.

But I think, catch here only wrong format exception.

As would be appropriate to make an exception?

```
def parse_date_if_not_null
  unless self.date_string.blank?
    begin
      self.ends_at = DateTime.strptime self.date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
    rescue
      errors.add(:date_string, _("Wrong date format, example: MM/DD/YYYY HH/MM"))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain a bit more about what you mean by "As would be appropriate to make an exception?"?  This isn't a good english sentence.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sorry, I was referring to, how to make the right exception.

Comment: What else do you want to validate?  In some situations you might want to specify that a date is only in the future, or only in the past, for example, but without any requirements it's impossible to say.  You should list, in normal language, what conditions you want to apply to the date, then somebody can tell you how to actually do that validation in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will be appropriate to make an exception in the model, you can do something like this..

```
class ...
  validate: parse_data_if_not_null

  def parse_data_if_not_null
    unless self.date_string.blank?
      erros.add(:date_string, 'Wrong date format, example: ...') if ((self.ends_at = DateTime.strptime self.date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError)
    end
end
```